# How do I create multiple pages within my domain using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a user goes to my domain `www.example.com` they see my webpage I created using React. I want to use React to show them a different webpage when they go to `www.example.com/anotherpage` instead.

This is the code I have in my index.js file which creates the webpage at `www.example.com`,

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Try out React Router https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solution for this, if you are creating an SPA with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-router/), then one of the most popular solution is by using [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

As shown in the example, then the basic routing is like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Route Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>Route About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Route Users</h2>;
}
```

However if you are using another framework such as [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), then they have the filesystem pages where creating a page under `/pages/` folder will create a new route.

Comment: Hey Robert. Thanks for the answer. I think your source code needs `function Home()...` and `About()` and `Users()` defined in order to work, as they are on the documentation https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Yes mate @Max, that is basically another component that I forgot to include in my answer! I'll include it so its clearer for everyone to see

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) for this purpose and declare separate routes for pages you want access to.

`npm install react-router-dom`

afterward, you can create separate components for the specific routes and attach them to the Routes as seen below,

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => <h1>hello world!</h1>

const AnotherPage = () => <div>Another page!</div>

const App = () => {
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/anotherpage" component={AnotherPage}
</Switch>
</Router>
}
export default App;
```

You can look at the documentation for more examples [react-router Quickstart](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `npm install react-router-dom` with nested routing for a better approach